# search in HEX for specific bytes

Tags: c, search, byte, buffer, hex

I have a `buffer[]` including HEX bytes and I want to search this buffer to find specific bytes. For example:

My buffer has `4096` bytes and I want to search in this if the bytes `45 34 67 23` (together) are inside this buffer (like searching a string in a buffer).

Have you any idea how can I do that? The programming language is C.

Comment: What language? Also, is the most naïve implementation somehow problematic? (i.e. find the first byte with value `45`, see if it's followed by `34 67 23`, if not, repeat until end of array)

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to say its for C language! sounds good this i.e. thank you :)

Comment: @Paul maybe his buffer contains 0x0 bytes?

Comment: @RedX: good point - if GNU/Linux then there is `memmem`

Answer (score 1):

Just "brute-force" it :)

```
haystacklen = 4096;
needlelen = 4;

foundat = -1;
index = 0; /* start at a different number if searching for 2nd occurrence */
while (index < haystacklen - needlelen + 1) {
    if ((buffer[index + 0] == 45)
     && (buffer[index + 1] == 34)
     && (buffer[index + 2] == 67)
     && (buffer[index + 3] == 23))
    {
        foundat = index;
    }
    index++;
}
/* foundat has the index of the 1st search bytes or -1 */
```

Comment: “When in doubt, use brute force” -- Ken Thompson

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while (index < haystacklen - needlelen)` ?

Comment: @Paul R: That would be `while (index <= haystacklen - needlelen)`. Pretend they're the same length: `haystacklen - needlelen` would be 0 and as `index` starts at 0, the loop would never run.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this much faster version. But you have to keep in mind that this only works for x86 / little endian processors because of the MAKEDWORD macro.

```
#define MAKEDWORD(a,b,c,d) ((uint32_t) (((uint32_t)a) & 0xFF) | ((((uint32_t)b) & 0xFF) << 8) | ((((uint32_t)c) & 0xFF) << 16) | ((((uint32_t)d) & 0xFF) << 24))
#define NEEDLE (MAKEDWORD(45,34,67,23))

// get the start and end address of the buffer
uint8_t *ptrEndBuffer = ((uint8_t*)buffer) + (4096 - sizeof(NEEDLE));
uint8_t *ptrStartBuffer = (uint8_t*)buffer - 1; // subtract -1 because we also want to get index 0

// while the result is not 0 we are good
while (ptrEndBuffer - ptrStartBuffer) {
    if ((*(uint32_t*)ptrEndBuffer) == NEEDLE) // get an whole integer instead of just one char
        break; // leave the loop if we found a match

    ptrEndBuffer--;
}

// the index will be -1 if we couldn't find a match else we subtract the start address + the 1 we first removed from the end buffer
int index = ((ptrEndBuffer == ptrStartBuffer) ? (-1) : (ptrEndBuffer - (ptrStartBuffer + 1)));
```

Comment: you could also do:
int index = (int)((int64_t)ptrEndBuffer - ((int64_t)ptrStartBuffer + 1)) // cast to long because if are working in the stack (high addresses) casting to int32_t could overflow the integers and render them negative